# Absolutely Positioned Sidebar gets extra margin on open

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, focus

I am using react and have made a sidebar which is animated in and out of screen but absolute position and changing css `right` of div. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-focus-on-popout-17179?file=/src/opener.tsx:213-237) is a sandbox for easy tweaking of code.

So when u click on blue box it should go out of screen by setting `right` to negative value and pink box should come out by setting `right` to `0`. As you can see this is not working.

BUT

If you remove the whole useEffect code in `popout.tsx` then everything works as expected.
The useEffect code is responsible for focusing and blurring the text input on the sidebar depending on the isOpen state.

Thank You!

EDIT

If you want to see what is expected behavior please comment out the the whole useEffect in the file `popout.tsx`. That is the expected behavior pink box out input focused pink box gone input blurred.

The idea of whole thing is the that blue box would have click me text and pink box open due to that or using key bind. Both these action should focus on text input inside.

Some Extra Info

There is also a key bind if you press `ctl + ~`  the pink box comes out thats why i have to change the focus depending on isOpem state and not click events.

Comment: But the pink box is meant to go back once the input is focused, right ?

Comment: no when the pink box is the screen the input should be focused and when pink is out of screen it should be blurred.

Comment: But currently the pink box is getting closed when input is focused

Comment: I have coded it so that when you click on pink box even on input(as input is box) it closes the pink box. That's not the point though i want it to auto focus when the pink box is opened. So as u can see in useEffect i am looking for changes inisOpen prop and depending on that prop setting focus in code. You can see that the pink box comes out input it is focused and when closed it is blurred just that the pink box comes out too much rather than right : 0 px as set in css. i didn't understand ur question properly but we don't want to focus on input by clicking on it that will result in clossing

Comment: normally we would close the pink box using a cross button on it but for now for simplicity i have put the click handler on the whole thing.

Comment: Can you try the `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`

Comment: OMG it works Thank you so much!!! I have to revise and understand these css concepts properly. You can put this as answer i will mark it correct if you want.

Comment: Glad that it worked. I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, you need to use `position: fixed` instead of the `position: absolute`.